# Menubar app with NSWindowController

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, menubar, nswindowcontroller

I'm currently trying to build a menubar app. Therefore I need a NSWindowController for an login field. It must be possible to open this NSWindowController when pressing a menu item and also close that window when the user clicked on cancel.

I used `showWindow(self)` and `NSApp.hide(self)` but this didn’t work for me. So has anyone an idea what I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Storyboard

- Add an `NSWindowController` to the storyboard and uncheck `visible at launch` of the window.
- In `AppDelegate` create a property `windowController`

  ```
  var windowController : NSWindowController!
  ```
- In `AppDelegate` create an `IBAction`.
- In the action get the main storyboard with

  ```
  let mainStoryBoard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), bundle: nil)
  ```
- Then instantiate and assign the window controller (the identifier must match the storyboard identifier)

  ```
  windowController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "Login")) as! NSWindowController
  ```
- Get the associated view controller (`LoginController` is the custom class of the view controller)

  ```
  let loginController = windowController.window!.contentViewController as! LoginController
  ```
- Show the main window

  ```
  windowController.showWindow(self)
  ```
- In Interface Builder connect the `NSMenuItem` to `First Responder` (red cube) and then to the created `IBAction`.

You can close the window either with the red `close` button or you need to add custom logic.

If you use a XIB create an `NSWindowController` subclass and load the XIB with `windowController = MyWindowController(window: nil)`, activate your app with `NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)` get the associated window with `let controllerWindow = windowController.window!` and show the window with `controllerWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)`

Comment: thank you for your answer! Sorry I don’t use Storyboards. What would be the way with a xib?

Comment: thank you, and I can close the window with NSAPP.hide(self) right?

Comment: No, that's not a good way. Set the delegate of the window to your controller. Then implement `windowWillClose()` and set the controller to `nil` to release the memory.